# How to customize look and feel of standard GWT components?

Tags: gwt

I have created GWT web application with standard Tree component from GWT. By default:
Tree
Implemented as a DIV containing nested TreeItems. The style name gwt-Tree applies to the DIV and the style overflow defaults to auto.
<div class="gwt-Tree" style="overflow: auto;">

<div style="position: relative; margin-left: 16;" (handle)>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

Where is the place in GWT source code where I can change Tree rendering on my own design?

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSS to style GWT components.

Here's a simple example using a [UIBinder template](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_Stylish_World):

```
<ui:style>
  .myTree {
    background-color: red;
  }
</ui:style>
<g:HTMLPanel>
  <g:Tree styleName="{style.myTree}" />
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

See this [developer's guide](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html) also.